# Solve problem with sets

Tags: combinatorics

I'm starting to study discrete math and found this problem on set theory:

In a survey to 100 people on electronic devices they own at home, it is known that 27 have a computer (C), 45 have a smart TV (T), 40 a video console (V) and 26 none of them. It is known that:

```
14 = |C ∩ T|
19 = |T ∩ V|
11 = |C ∩ V|
```

1. How many have all three?

There are `|C ∩ T ∩ V|` participants have all three, but I don't know how to calculate this from the data I have. Any hints to solve this problem?

Comment: Given that there are two choices for each category (either a person has an object in that category or they don't) and given that there are $3$ categories, there are $2^3=8$ possible types of individuals. You are given $7$ bits of information, and you know the total.  So the data should suffice.  Try to use the data to compute the number of people of each type.

Comment: Use inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add up $|C|, |T|, |V|$ you will count some people twice, or even three times.  If you subtract each of $|C\cap T|, |T\cap C|, |V\cap C|$, then you remove the extra people you counted twice.  However the people you counted three times (that is the people in $C\cap T\cap V$) will now be counted three times and discounted three times.

So you know exactly how many people are not in $C\cap T\cap V$, but are in $C\cup T\cup V$.  You know $|C\cup T\cup V|$ so subtracting the people in $C\cup T\cup V$ but not $C\cap T\cap V$ from this, leaves $|C\cap T\cap V|$.

Note a generalisation of this idea is called the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: Thank you. I managed to solve the problem, it was simpler than I thought.